# when should i pass a vector parameter by reference versus passing one by value?

Tags: c++, function, vector, parameters

when am i supposed to add in the ampersand? i have some examples from my hw:

How should a function's vector parameter ages be defined for the following situations?

1)ages will always be small (fewer than 10 elements) and the function will not modify the vector.
ANSWER: Constant but not pass by reference.

2)ages will always be small, and the function will modify the vector.
ANSWER: Pass by reference but not constant

I understand the not constant part.. but not the pass by reference :/ why do i add in the ampersand to make it pass by reference versus not

Comment: It's very hard to make sense of the statements. For example, when you say the function will modify the vector, does that mean that those modifications must be preserved when the function returns or must not be preserved? It's not clear which of two opposite meanings that phrase has.

Comment: it wasnt clear in the instructions either. that is all that it gave me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far more simpler than your homework suggests, but for the sake of getting the correct marks:

It talks about how the `vector` will be small, because COPYING a large vector can be costly (performance wise). If your function will not modify the `vector`, and the `vector` will be small, then simply passing a copy will do. An example would be a function to print the `vector`:

```
void print(const std::vector<int> v) // const because we don't modify v
{
    for (auto i : v)
       std::cout << i << ", ";
}
```

When instead we have a function that needs to modify the `vector` (and those changes need to be observed once the function ends) a reference makes more sense:

```
void removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& v)
{        
}
```

Here `removeDuplicates` takes a non-const reference, because it modifies it. Regardless of the size of the `vector`, we expect the function to modify the passed in `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
// populate v
...
removeDuplicates(v);
// v may now be different
```

If instead you had a function which modifies the arguments, but those modifications shouldn't be seen outside the function, a non-const copy would suffice. Imagine that our `print` function printed elements rounded to the nearest `100` (sure we could do that on the fly, but we might alter the `vector` first and then call our original `print`).

For real-world advice, you should typically just pass a copy, unless:
* your function is storing a reference the passed parameter, or
* modifying it where changes need to be observed once the function ends

Answer (score 1):

Passing by reference will allow the function to modify the actual data of the argument - which means any changes that happen inside of the function will be persisted after the function has returned.

Passing by value means that the function is working with a copy of the data.

In some situations, such as if you're working with very large data sets, passing by value can cause performance issues since there is so much data to copy (and in rare situations where you're working with extremely limited memory, passing by value may not even be an option.) In these cases you would pass by `const` reference so that you don't have to give the function its own copy of the data *and* the function doesn't modify the actual data being passed in.